# Apply different effects on CAReplicatorLayer instances

Tags: ios, swift, swift2, core-animation, swift-playground

I am trying to use the replicator layer to create a reflection of my original layer. The problem is I want to apply a different effect on each instance (Rasterize the copy, but keep the original intact). Is this possible using replicator layers, and if not can you suggest a way of achieving this?

Note: I tried duplicating the layers, but I could not because they get copied by reference and thus any effect applied to one is applied to the original layer.

```
let r = CAReplicatorLayer()
r.bounds = CGRect(x: 0.0, y: 0.0, width: background.frame.width , height: background.frame.height)
r.position = background.center
background.layer.addSublayer(r)

r.addSublayer(masterLayer)
r.instanceCount = 2
r.instanceTransform = CATransform3DMakeRotation(CGFloat(M_PI), 1, 0, 0)
r.masksToBounds = true
r.shouldRasterize = true
r.rasterizationScale = 0.2
```

Answer (score 4):

Yes, one of the limitations of CAReplicatorLayer is that you don't have direct access to the individual replicated instances.

You can try bypassing CAReplicatorLayer altogether and instead create your own subclass of CALayer, give it an array property to hold the replicated sublayers (allowing you direct access to each of those sublayers) and then endow it with whatever CAReplicator-like abilities you require. This won't be a drop-in replacement for CAReplicatorLayer, of course, and I can't say if it's the solution you're looking for (without knowing the specifics of what you're trying to achieve with those individual layers) but you may want to give it a shot.

I posted a short write-up on this some months ago [here](http://www.mojolama.com/creating-custom-replicator-views) (source code [here](https://github.com/abeldomingues/Custom-Replicator-View)) if you're interested. Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you. I just need to make sure that my animations are synced across the layers and be able to apply different effects on each layer separately.